# Show that a transitive subgroup of symmetric group is primitive

Tags: permutations, finite-groups

I am working on this exercise 1.5.7 of Dixon-Mortimer Permutation Groups: Let $G \leqslant \mathrm{Sym}(\Omega)$ be a transitive group and let $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ be finite subsets of $\Omega$. Suppose $G_{(\Gamma)}$ and $G_{(\Delta)}$ act primitively on $\Omega\setminus\Gamma$ and $\Omega\setminus\Delta$ respectively, and $G = \langle G_{(\Gamma)}, G_{(\Delta)}\rangle$. Show that the group G is primitve.

Now, when this question says that  $G_{(\Gamma)}$ acts primitively on $\Omega\setminus\Gamma$, does it imply that it acts primitively on $\Delta$? But we don't have this information that $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are disjoint. If not, then what would be the blocks (in this case the singleton sets) for $G_{(\Gamma)}$? Same goes for $G_{(\Delta)}$. Any kind of help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: If $\omega\in\Delta\cap\Gamma$, then $\omega$ is fixed by every element of $G_{(\Gamma)}$ and of $G_{(\Delta)}$, hence is fixed by $\langle G_{(\Gamma)},G_{(\Delta)}\rangle=G$, contradicting that $G$ is transitive on $\Omega$. But note that you do not even know if $G_{(\Gamma)}$ even acts on $\Delta$: there is no reason to assume that $\delta^g\in \Delta$ for $\delta\in \Delta$ and $g\in G_{(\Gamma)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach: we already know $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are disjoint. Since $G$ is transitive, all blocks would have the same size; assume we have blocks larger than singletons, and we show there's only one block, implying $G$ is primitive. Let $x\in\Gamma$ and $B$ the block containing $x$. Since for all $g\in G_{(\Gamma)}$, we have $B\cap Bg$ nonempty, we must have $Bg=B$, so that $G_{(\Gamma)}$ fixes $B$. Now $B\cap\Delta^c$ is a nonempty block for $G_{(\Delta)}$, so by primitivity either $B\cap\Delta^c=\{x\}$ or $B\cap\Delta^c=\Delta^c$. In the first case, since $|B|>1$, it contains some $y\in\Delta$, so as above $G_{(\Delta)}$ fixes $B$, so $G$ fixes $B$, and $B=\Omega$. If $\Delta^c\subset B$, then again $G_{(\Delta)}$ fixes $B$ so that again $B=\Omega$.

Comment: Yes, this is a smarter approach. I just don't play with blocks often enough...

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify : all blocks would have the same size since $G$ has only one orbit, so the $G$-congruence on $\Omega$ would create an equipartition of $\Omega$, right? Another doubt for me would be why is $B \cap \Delta^c$ be a nonempty block for $G_{(Δ)}$. The rest I understand.

Comment: Yes, exactly, to your first question. $B\cap\Delta^c$ is nonempty because it contains $x$, and the disjointness implies $\Gamma\subset\Delta^c$.

Comment: Oh, okay! I get it now, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There may be easier ways of doing this; I'm just "following my nose", as I don't work much with permutation groups on a regular basis.

$G_{(\Gamma)}=\{g\in G\mid \gamma^g=\gamma\text{ for all }\gamma\in\Gamma\}$, and similarly for $G_{(\Delta)}$.

No, you cannot conclude that $G_{(\Gamma)}$ acts primitively on $\Delta$: you don't even know that it acts on $\Delta$ at all! For example, consider the case of $G=S_{4}$, $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\Gamma=\{1\}$, and $\Delta=\{4\}$. Then $G_{(\Gamma)}$ is the point stabilizer of $1$, which acts primitively on $\{2,3,4\}$, but does not act on $\{4\}$, since there are elements of $G_{(\Gamma)}$ that sends $4$ to $3$. Note that here $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ *are* disjoint, so that isn't even the issue.

But in fact $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ must be disjoint unless $\Omega$ is a singleton: assume $\Omega$ is not a singleton. If $\omega\in\Gamma\cap\Delta$, then $\omega^g=\omega$ for all $g\in G_{(\Gamma)}$ and for all $g\in G_{(\Delta)}$. But since $G=\langle G_{(\Gamma)},G_{(\Delta)}\rangle$, that implies that $\omega^x=\omega$ for all $x\in G$, which contradicts that $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega$. So in fact we know that $\Delta\cap\Gamma=\varnothing$.

(Well, technically we must consider the case of $\Omega=\{\bullet\}$, but then the problem is trivial, since any action on this set is both trivial and primitive.)

We also have that $\Delta\cup\Gamma\neq\Omega$ (unless one of them is empty). Indeed, if $\Delta\cup\Gamma=\Omega$, then elements of $G_{(\Gamma)}$ sends elements of $\Gamma$ to $\Gamma$ and elements of $\Omega\setminus\Gamma=\Delta$ to $\Delta$, and symmetrically for $G_{(\Delta)}$. But then every element of $G=\langle G_{(\Gamma)},G_{(\Delta)}\rangle$ would respect the partition $\Omega=\Gamma\amalg\Delta$, again contradicting transitivity of the action.

So let $B$ be a block, and let $x,y\in B$, $x\neq y$. We want to show that $B=\Omega$. Using transitivity, we may assume that $x$ lies in both $\Omega\setminus\Gamma$ and in $\Omega\setminus\Delta$, because $(\Omega\setminus\Gamma)\cap(\Omega\setminus\Delta) = \Omega\setminus(\Gamma\cup\Delta)\neq\varnothing$.

Because $y\neq x$, $B$ contains at least two elements of $\Omega\setminus\Gamma$ or two elements of $\Omega\setminus\Delta$; without loss of generality say two elements of $\Omega\setminus\Gamma$. Because any block of $G$ is also a block of $G_{(\Gamma)}$, and a block of $G_{(\Gamma)}$ must either contain all of $\Omega\setminus\Gamma$ or intersect it at a singleton, it follows that $\Omega\setminus \Gamma\subseteq B$. In particular, $\Delta\subseteq B$.

If $B\setminus\Delta=\{x\}$, then $B=\Delta\cup\{x\}$; since $\Delta,\{x\}\subseteq\Omega\setminus\Gamma$, then we in fact have $B=\Delta\cup\{x\}=\Omega\setminus\Gamma$. Which means every element of $G_{(\Delta)}$ fixes $B$ pointwise, and every element of $G_{(\Gamma)}$ sends $B$ to itself. But this means that $G=\langle G_{(\Delta)},G_{(\Gamma)}\rangle$ acts on $B$, and since the action is transitive, this gives $B=\Omega$, which is what we wanted.

If $B\setminus\Delta$ contains more than one element, then $B\cap(\Omega\setminus\Delta)$ has at least two elements, and the symmetric argument from before gives $\Omega\setminus\Delta\subseteq B$. Thus, we have
$$B\supseteq(\Omega\setminus \Delta)\cup (\Omega\setminus\Gamma) = \Omega\setminus(\Delta\cap\Gamma) = \Omega,$$
which again proves $B=\Omega$.

Thus, if $B$ is a block with more than two elements, then $B=\Omega$, which proves the action of $G$ on $\Omega$ is primitive, as required.

Comment: The whole was a bit hard to follow, but the counterexample at the beginning made me realise where I was going wrong. Thank you very much! As an undergrad, trying to study Mortimer-Dixon is very challenging but fun at the same time.